# Populate a field with values from two other fields using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

I'd like to populate a 'Full Name' field automatically with what the user types into the 'First Name' and 'Last Name' fields, so if they type 'John' and 'Smith' into the first and last name fields, the 'Full Name' field would be dynamically populated with 'John Smith'.

I'm not very good with jQuery so have only managed to populate the field with the 'First Name' so far after searching through other examples.

My current code is below, and any help on this would be appreciated.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#first_name').keyup(function () {
        $('#full_name').val(this.value);
    });
});
</script>

<input type="text" name="full_name" id="full_name" value="" />
<input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="" />
<input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="" />
```

Thanks,

Ste

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
$('#first_name').keyup(function(){
   $('#full_name').val(this.value+' '+$('#last_name').val());
});

$('#last_name').keyup(function(){
   $('#full_name').val($('#first_name').val()+' '+this.value);
});
```

Comment: Or you can use 
$('#first_name, #last_name').keyup(function(){
   $('#full_name').val($('#first_name').val()+' '+$('#last_name').val());
});

Comment: Both of these worked great, so I've gone with the second one as it was less lines. :-) Thanks for your help with this, much appreciated.